# PHP assign default array key for all items

Tags: arrays

I am converting a comma separated string into an array. By default it will set each array item with a number (0,1,2,3...).

Is it possible to set a specific key to be used instead (for every item in the array), in this case: **name**

**Current array**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 'tagtest'
  1 => 'jordan'
  2 => 'hello'
  3 => 'world'
  4 => 'tagtest'
```

**Expected array**

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => 'tagtest'
  'name' => 'jordan'
  'name' => 'hello'
  'name' => 'world'
  'name' => 'tagtest'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is imposible. Because we cant return any value

`$arr["name"] = ?`

You have 2 ways to achive the similar result by

`$names = […]; //dedicated array`
 or 
`$arr["names"] = […] // another array set to the key`